# Need to create a controller that deactivates a user.

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

The following code is the deactivate method:

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/deactivate")
public boolean deactivateAccount(@RequestBody SomeReqBean someReqBean) {

 //code already finished
```

}
 I am looking to see how I can go about creating a controller that will allow me to deactivate a user upon request from a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood from your question is that you want to deactivate a user after clicking on submit button.
There're several ways to do that.
The simpler way is that :--

**1.) Create a column in your user table by the name 'status' (or anything you want)**

**2.) When you're creating a user save the value of that 'status' column to 1 for that userID (status = 1 means, this user is currently in active state)**

**3.) Now, when you want to deactivate that user, simply update that 'status' value to 0**

So, your code will be something like this :---

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/deactivate")
        public boolean deactivateAccount(@RequestBody String user_id) {

        boolean statusFlag =  your further query to update user's status field in DB to 0

    if(statusFlag){
          //means status is successfully updated in DB
          return true;
    }else{
          return false;

         }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. So the program is suppose to call a user and his/her information will populated the fields. And if the user decides to deactivate account then the deactivate button should deactivate the user. I'm using thymeleaf/spring should there be something in  the HTML file?

Comment: You need **unique id** of the user (which identity that user in DB) which you want to delete or deactivate from DataBase after clicking on 'de-activate' button. Simpler way to handle this thing is to send the unique-id lets say user_id of that user when s/he clicks on deactivate button, to your spring controller.
For better understanding on how to send parameters from your theymleaf to controller , here's the link to help you out better (PS - this question is almost identical what you're looking for) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794057/thymeleaf-send-parameter-from-html-to-controller

Comment: Thank you Sumit. That link is basically exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't ask the right way. Much appreciated.